# MySQL replication to another server

Tags: mysql, mysql-backup

I have an application that uses MySQL. I also have 2 different servers where I have installed MySQL. I am inserting manual the records to both databases in order to have a backup database. Is it an internal MySQL function to automatically do a backup to a different server without inserting twice? If yes, what do I need to do?

Is MySQL replication via MySQL utilities or MySQL Cluster what I need?

Comment: Have you tried regularly doing mysqldump? You don't need to replicate the records to another db... mysqldump will do...If your main dB failed, you'll just reload the dumped file...

Comment: See this MySQL documentation http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/7218/replication#t=201611230821097328931